# In Powerpoint VBA, how do I get the current position of a shape that is moving along its motion path?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to spawn a new shape at the position of moving shape (crosshair) that is moving along a custom path. I can add a shape and create it but the Top and Left position is the original position of the shape. I have looked at the effects object information and there does not appear to be any information about the current position of the shape on its path.

I've debated using the path from .Behaviors(1).MotionEffect.Path and calculate the position based on time passed, but there are too many ways that the timing of the motion can be impacted with ease in and ease out settings, etc. Ideally there is some presentation data somewhere that can be accessed in VBA that includes the current state of the shape in the rendered slide.